# Caffe Checkerboard artefacts, how to fix this?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am using Caffe and I use my Deconvolution Layer like this:

```
layer {
  name: "name"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "bottom
  top: "top"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    bias_term: false
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 2
    group: 256
    stride: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "bilinear"
    }
  }
}
```

When finishing the training and validating my network, I receive weird checkerboard artefacts. I could not find anything about how to fix this problem in Caffe so I am asking here if anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple:

```
layer {
  name: "name"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "bottom
  top: "top"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    bias_term: false
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 4   # <-- changing kernel size fixed the problem.
    group: 256
    stride: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "bilinear"
    }
  }
}
```

An example is provided under this [link](https://gist.github.com/tnarihi/54744612d35776f53278)

Comment: what is the answer here? you just changed the `kernel_size`? can you elaborate?

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer! This is the correct answer, what else do you need? @Shai

Comment: See one answer above mine, there you can find a link. @Shai

Comment: @Shai this layer does not "learn" anything am I right? It just does bilinear upsampling?

Comment: if your `lr_mult` and `decay_mult` are zero, the weights are not updating.

Comment: As you can see this is the case for me since I set them to zero? @Shai

Answer (score 3):

This problem is not specific to Caffe, it happens because of Deconvolution. A very good analysis and solution is provided at http://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/ There are several simple method to prevent this problem:

- Use a stride of one.
- Reduce the use of Deconvolution in the network, like only in the last layer.
- Upsample the feature map before applying Deconvolution (resize-convolution mentioned in the article).

Comment: Okay, your first step is easy to accomplish in caffe, however step 2 is not possible for me and step 3 is in my opinion no possible in caffe, could you help me with step 3?

Comment: Actually, use stride of one, is not very easy either!! How would you do that in my case?

Comment: @thigi What do you mean it is not very easy?

Comment: Firstly, in your article they talk about overlaps, but in my implementation: stride: 2 kernel_size: 2 there is no overlap. Secondly, could you give me an example, using stride: 1 which I could use to replace my code (--> I think that is not possible). and for the 3rd bullet point my question is: Is that even possible in caffe?

Comment: Yeah since I use: kernel_size: 2 and stride: 2, my question is still not answered, cause I think that your answer only applies to overlapping kernels, which is not the case for me.

Comment: Here is a link how Upsampling works in caffe: [Deconvolution](https://github.com/tnarihi/caffe/commit/4f249a00a29432e0bb6723087ec64187e1506f0f) It says that the Deconvolution layer in caffe behaves like the sicily function: (in line 190) skimage.transform.rescale(img, factor, mode='constant', cval=0)

Comment: Plus here: [link](https://gist.github.com/tnarihi/54744612d35776f53278) I think my problem is that I have to use: kernel_size: 4, stride: 2 and padding: 1. I will try this and let you know if it works!

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform bilinear upsampling by some known factor it is not enough to make a Deconvolution layer with a bilinear weight filler. You also need to set up stride, padding and kernel size correctly.
If we imagine the whole process as painting, kernel is our brush and stride describes how often we touch it to the canvas. Choosing too small kernel with too large stride results in output will look like we put tiny specks of paint wide apart. Too large kernel introduces excessive blurring. Checkerboards arise when your kernel does not initialize correctly - currently ([latest commit when typing this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/commit/4efdf7ee49cffefdd7ea099c00dc5ea327640f04)), caffe contains a bug with bilinear filter generation and for some sizes it will not actually be bilinear (proposed fix in PR [#5713](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/5713)).

Formulas to select the right size/stride/padding are given in [BilinearFiller documentation](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1BilinearFiller.html#details).

Comment: No it is not. I understand that your answer is how _you_ solved your specific problem - upscaling by a factor of 2 - but mine provides a general explanation of the matter, not just a raw code snippet.

Comment: Yeah thats true, do you wanna combine the two solutions?